# How to Scrape JSON Data Using Scrapy

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy, python-3.6

I'm using scrapy and I'm trying to test my selector using scrapy shell but nothing is working.  I'm trying to scrape the JSON data on this website.

https://web.archive.org/web/20180604230058/https://api.simon.com/v1.2/tenant?mallId=231&key=40A6F8C3-3678-410D-86A5-BAEE2804C8F2&lw=true

I've tried to scrape the data using the selector

```
   response.css("body > pre::text").extract()
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working.  Not sure what's wrong...

Ideally, I just want to get all the "Name: XXX" elements from the JSON data.  So If you know how to select those specifically, that would be very helpful as well!

Currently my code looks like this

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import scrapy # needed to scrape
    import sys    # need to import xlrd
    sys.path.extend("/Users/YoungFreeesh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
    packages/") # needed to import xlrd
    import xlrd   # used to easily import xlsx file 

    class AmazonbotSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'ArchiveSpider'

        allowed_domains = ['web.archive.org']
        start_urls =['https://web.archive.org/web/20180604230058/https://api.simon.com/v1.2/tenant?mallId=231&key=40A6F8C3-3678-410D-86A5-BAEE2804C8F2&lw=true']

        def parse(self, response):
            print(response.body)
```

Comment: Re: "this doesn't seem to be working" — not sure anyone is a mind reader here. I could be wrong though...

Comment: I checked the networks log and it loads the json file from this url https://web.archive.org/web/20180604230058if_/https://api.simon.com/v1.2/tenant?mallId=231&key=40A6F8C3-3678-410D-86A5-BAEE2804C8F2&lw=true .. Difference between both urls is 'if_'. See if this pattern matches with other links you have. You can use this hack to get your data.

Comment: @SP_ Thanks! That works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the content is inside an `iframe`, it is a separate page, you have to navigate to the iframe first. Like a link, something like that:

```
urls = response.css('iframe::attr(src)').extract()
for url in urls :
    yield scrapy.Request(url...., target=parse_iframe)
```

then define a  new `parse_iframe` method where you parse the iframes response.

Comment: Here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52779161/python-scrapy-json-xpath-how-to-scrape-json-data-with-scrapy/52779299#52779299

Could you please answer?